# Multiply previous row value by constant R

Tags: r, dataframe

Have a simple R question but cannot seem to find an answer:

I have a data frame like this:

```
assumption_val year
1.2            2015
0              2016
0              2017
0              2018
0              2019
```

I want to grow each value as 20% greater than compared to the previous year, to output something like this:

```
assumption_val year
1.2            2015
1.44           2016
1.73           2017
2.07           2018
2.49           2019
```

How can I reference the previous row and multiply it by 1.2 to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking for `cumprod`:

```
cumprod(rep(1.2, 5))
```

Like its better known friend, `cumsum`, it accumulates past results, but it performs a multiplication rather than addition.

```
df <- data.frame(assumption_val=cumprod(rep(1.2, 5)), 
                 years=2015:2019)
```

A nice generalization of these functions is `Reduce`. For example, here is `Reduce` performing this calculation. You can replace the "*" with "+" and have `cumsum`.

```
Reduce("*", rep(1.2, 5), accumulate = T)
```

A nice feature of this method is that you can adjust the growth rate in each period. For instance if you wanted to start at 1.5 rather than 1.2, you would simply adjust your growth vector to `c(1.5, rep(1.2, 4))` to calculate the new growth as follows:

```
cumprod(c(1.5, rep(1.2, 4)))
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! New scenario - the first assumption just so happens to be the same as what you'd multiply as the growth rate. How would the code change if the first value was say, 1.5, but you still wanted 20% growth yearly?

Comment: See the bottom section of the answer that I added.

Answer (score 3):

```
data <- read.table(textConnection("
    assumption_val year
    1.2            2015
    0              2016
    0              2017
    0              2018
    0              2019"), header = TRUE)

data$assumption_val <- data$assumption_val[1]^(1:nrow(data))

data
##   assumption_val year
## 1        1.20000 2015
## 2        1.44000 2016
## 3        1.72800 2017
## 4        2.07360 2018
## 5        2.48832 2019
```