# iteratively multiply the values of a row in R

Tags: r, indexing, apply

I am trying to compute a new vector of values, based on the observations in a row in a dataframe. I want to start with the first value, multiply this by the second value, then multiply the third value by the value I just calculated. I'm not sure how to reference a value which doesn't exist until I've calculated it.

This is what I would do if I were writing this out longhand:

```
index1 <- rnorm(12)
index2 <- rnorm(12)  
index3 <- rnorm(12)
index4 <- rnorm(12)
index5 <- rnorm(12)
data <- rbind(index1, index2, index3, index4, index5)

splice1=data[2,1]
splice2=splice1*data[2,2]
splice3=splice2*data[2,3]
splice4=splice3*data[2,4]
splice5=splice4*data[2,5]

splices <- c(splice1, splice2, splice3, splice4, splice5)
```

I need to do this for 25 rows of data.

I found this post
[Multiply previous row value by constant R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37421173/multiply-previous-row-value-by-constant-r)
But I can't figure out how to make this work when you are referencing by indexing from the dataset.

I'm sure there must be an easy way to do this, but I wasn't sure where to start.

Thanks heaps for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`?apply` the `?cumprod` function over each row of data:

```
t(apply(data, 1, cumprod))

#              [,1]        [,2]        [,3]       [,4]          [,5]
#index1  0.37891415  1.02182094  0.62823228 0.03616281 -0.0262988311
#index2 -0.06586518 -0.03332061 -0.02814185 0.01755643 -0.0238307051
#index3 -0.09113830  0.13385726 -0.11245386 0.10917885 -0.1466176651
#index4 -0.53727635  0.71947970  0.87007225 0.19779160 -0.2119473091
#index5 -0.83982393 -0.08571211 -0.08986865 0.02597184 -0.0006549512
```

Row 2 here looks familiar:

```
splices
#     index2      index2      index2      index2      index2 
#-0.06586518 -0.03332061 -0.02814185  0.01755643 -0.02383071
```

`cumprod()` is essentially just multiplying along each supplied set of numbers, a `cum`ulative `prod`uct:

```
cumprod(1:5)
#[1]   1   2   6  24 120
```

If speed is an issue, you can look to the `matrixStats` package:

```
library(matrixStats)
rowCumprods(data)
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this. Much appreciated.